# Responsive multiple background images in body

Tags: html, css

I want to know if it's possible to make multiple backgrounds (inside the body) responsive.

I have three, they are at a certain distance that can't be fixed in px, I tried using media queries but I would have to do a million for this to work in each one of them.

This is my code example:

```
body {
background: url(../img/1.svg), url(../img/2.svg), url(../img/3.svg);
background-position: 65% 7%, center 62%, left bottom;
background-size: 850px auto, contain, 200%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

If this is not possible, how can I achieve it? This are backgrounds of sections made as vectors, but they overflow to other divs, so I'm not sure if there is other possible way.

This is an example:

[image]

Comment: Could you give an example of the "overflowed" version looks?

Answer (score 1):

Define `width:100%`

```
img{
    width:100%;
    background: url(../img/1.svg), url(../img/2.svg), url(../img/3.svg);
    background-position: 65% 7%, center 62%, left bottom;
    background-size: 850px auto, contain, 200%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a body that has this backgrounds, I forgot to mention it, so this wouldn't work.